# Using Notepad++, how to find certain character(s) in every line in position X

Tags: notepad++, regex

I frequently work in rather large (30+ meg) text based data files and I need to find every line that has a specific character in a specific position and make a few manual updates to those lines.  There are only a rather small number (45 or so) lines that have the given character in the position but I can't seem to get a regex to work to search for it.  For example, sometimes I need to search for "G" in position 25 and other times I need to search for "CNW" in positions 15, 16, 17. What regular expression can I use to find these?

Comment: [regex to match character in specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789929/regex-to-match-character-in-specific-position).

Comment: Sandeep, thanks for the link but that doesn't seem to work for me. Using notepad++ v7.5.6 in the find dialog I have the search mode set to Regular Expression but /^.{13}0/ results in "Find: Can't find the text "/^.{13}0/" "  It looks like it's not doing the search based on the regex but rather just searching for that text.  Admittedly (and obviously), I'm new to using regex in Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:.{24}G|.{14}CNW).*$`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of line
  (?:           : start non capture group
    .{24}G      : 24 any character but newline then the letter G
   |            : OR
    .{14}CNW    : 14 any character but newline then the letters CNW
  )             : end group
  .*            : 0 or more any character but newline
$               : end of line
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much.  I marked your response as useful but since I just registered, it doesn't count yet so please know I am very grateful for your answer! (and the easy to understand explanation!)

Comment: @Scott: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @Scott: You have not enough reputatin to upvote, but you can mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers